# Grammar inference library?

Tags: python, java, ruby, grammar-induction

What are the best (or any) open source libraries for regular or context-free grammar inference from a set of examples believed to be generated by a common grammar?  I'd prefer a good library in Java, Python or Ruby, but of course beggars can't be choosers.

I did some googling, but couldn't find any actual implementations, though I did find plenty of interesting references.  [This library](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/dload/20030604-Seminar/max0604_mical_slides.pdf) looks interesting, but I couldn't find it available for download anywhere.

Edit (2011-11-14): For clarity (though I'm not sure how you all misunderstood), the question was about grammar inference, not grammar generation or parsing.  In other words, given a set of strings which accord to an unknown grammar, find the most restrictive grammar which they all satisfy.

Comment: There are several libraries that implement [DFA learning algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512918/grammatical-inference-of-regular-expressions-for-given-finite-list-of-representa/15519725#15519725) for grammar induction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not used them yet, but I had this identical question and (after much searching) found these two libraries, at very least:

- [libalf](http://libalf.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/index.php?page=about) for C++
- [gitoolbox](https://code.google.com/p/gitoolbox/) for MATLAB

Unlike the other answers to the question, these are actual **grammar inference libraries** rather than **parser generators**.

Comment: Link to other question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512918/grammatical-inference-of-regular-expressions-for-given-finite-list-of-representa/15529092

Answer (score -2):

You can have a look at antlr - http://www.antlr.org/
and see if its what you're looking for.

Comment: That is not to do inference/induction. You are actually supposed to already *have* the language and just specify it there.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at Parboiled: https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled
It doesn't generates any sources, just create a class in your app, define a model in it, and make a call from your code.

Comment: that is no grammar inference.