# How to programmatically learn regexes?

Tags: regex, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

My question is a continuation of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512918/grammatical-inference-of-regular-expressions-for-given-finite-list-of-representa).  Basically, I have a table of words like so:

```
HAT18178_890909.098070313.1
HAT18178_890909.098070313.2
HAT18178_890909.143412462.1
HAT18178_890909.143412462.2
```

For my purposes, I do not need the terminal `.1` or `.2` for this set of names.  I can manually write the following regex (using Python syntax):

```
r = re.compile('(.*\.\d+)\.\d+')
```

However, I cannot guarantee that my next set of names will have a similar structure where the final 2 characters will be discardable - it could be 3 characters (i.e. `.12`) and the separator could change as well (i.e. `.` to `_`).

What is the appropriate way to either explicitly learn a regex or to determine which characters are unnecessary?

Comment: what do you mean, "learn a regex"? Learn regex syntax, or "what does this particular usage of a regex mean"? Regex is a language, and you learn the rules. But knowing the rules doesn't mean you'll suddenly be able to slam out the regex equivalent of "shall I compare thee to a summer's day?"

Comment: How do you know that you don't need the `.1`?  Whatever criteria you used to figure that out will be relevant in your learning algorithm.

Comment: @MarcB: From the previous question, it *looks* like OP wants some kind of machine learning.

Comment: @Kevin yes, that's right. The point is to learn the common pattern in the strings that I have encapsulated in the (Python)  regex.

Comment: Split on punctuation.

Comment: @MarcB - the question isn't 'wutz a regex' or 'n e have regex plz'.  I specifically want to know if someone has worked an algorithm for taking in a set of strings and learning the different levels of patterns common to them.  I can code my perception of the patterns just fine; I am wondering if a computer can learn what I see.

Comment: sure, it's possible. easy? probably not. "neural nets" and whatever other AI-related buzzwords. you can whip up an algorithm to figure out the differences between a set of strings and probably have it build a regex for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting problem.

```
X                                  y
HAT18178_890909.098070313.1        HAT18178_890909.098070313
HAT18178_890909.098070313.2        HAT18178_890909.098070313
HAT18178_890909.143412462.1        HAT18178_890909.143412462 
HAT18178_890909.143412462.2        HAT18178_890909.143412462
```

The problem is that there is not a single solution but **many**.

Even for a human it is not clear what the regex should be that you want.

Based on this data, I would think the possibilities to learn are:

Just match a fixed width of 25: `.{25}`

Fixed first part: `HAT18178_890909.`

Then:

There's only 2 varying numbers on each single spot (as you show 2 cases).
So e.g. `[01]` (either 0 or 1), `[94]` the next spot and so on would be a good solution.

The obvious one would be `\d+`

But it could also be `\d{9}`

You see, there are multiple correct answers.

These regexes would still work if the second point would be an underscore instead.

My conclusion:

The problem is that it is much more work to prepare the data for machine learning than it is to create a regex. If you want to be sure you cover everything, you need to have complete data, so then a regex is probably less effort.

Answer (score -1):

You could split on non-alphanumeric characters;

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9']+
```

That would get you, in this case, few strings like this:

```
HAT18178
890909
098070313
1
```

From there on you can simply discard the last one if that's never necessary, and continue on processing the first sequences